# How to solve char and numbers together in switch case statement?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors

I want to take user input that can either be 3, AB, ab, Ab, or aB that is stored in one variable. We are told to only use char as datatype but the problem is, char only holds one character. How do I solve this problem?

```
case 3:
        case 3="AB":
        case 3="ab":
        case 3="Ab":
        case 3="aB":
```

I get the error as shown below:

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment.
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please provide more code as context.

Comment: I want to take user input that can either be 3, AB, Ab, ab, or aB using switch case. We are only allowed to use char as datatype. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: The first step would be to research how a switch works and what the correct syntax should be. But you can't use a `switch` with strings or string literals, so you might be looking for an `if` instead.

Comment: You cannot read `AB` into a `char`, because those are two chars. You could either read input into two separate `char` variables and have nested switches, or read `AB` as string and use if/else chain.

Comment: You can't use `switch` with strings.  (Part of the point of this exercise is probably realizing that you can read a sequence of digits as a string.)

Comment: I kinda already solved this problem by changing the datatype but they said we are supposed to use char. The thing is, char only takes one character. Maybe it's a trick question.

Comment: `"AB"` is a string, which is represented as an *array* of `char`.   Only integral values can be used in a `switch`/`case`.   While `char` is an integral type, an array of `char` (like an array of any other integral type) is not an integral value - it is a set of integral values - so cannot be used in a `switch`/`case`.

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, you can only store a single letter in `char` variable. If you are required by task to use `switch` and `char` only, you can use two `char` variables and nested `switch`:

```
char a, b;
std::cin >> a >> b;
switch (a)
{
    case 'A':
        switch (b)
        {
             case 'B':
                 std::cout << "AB here";
             break;
             case 'b':
                  std::cout << "Ab here";
             break;
        }
        break;
    case 'a':
        switch (b)
        {
             case 'B':
                 std::cout << "aB here";
             break;
             case 'b':
                  std::cout << "ab here";
             break;
        }
        break;
}
```

Notice that there's a lot of code duplication, and it's far from easy to understand.

You can also limit it one `char` variable by reading into the same variable before inner switches (and some more code duplication):

```
char a;
std::cin >> a;
switch (a)
{
    case 'A':
        std::cin >> a;
        switch (a)
        {
             case 'B':
                 std::cout << "AB here";
             break;
             case 'b':
                  std::cout << "Ab here";
             break;
        }
        break;
    case 'a':
        std::cin >> a;
        switch (a)
        {
             case 'B':
                 std::cout << "aB here";
             break;
             case 'b':
                  std::cout << "ab here";
             break;
        }
        break;
}
```

Or (the best solution) just use if/else chain:

```cpp
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;
if(input == "AB")
{
}
else if(input == "Ab")
{
}
else if(input == "aB")
{
}
else if(input == "ab")
{
}
else
{
std::cout << "wrong input!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the char datatype in c++ can only store one character at a time
which means you can not store two alphabets at the same time (like AB, aB e.t.c)
instead, you can only store A, B, a, b, or single alphabets.

as for storing 3 in char datatype,
a char variable is stored in 1 byte and an int variable is stored in 4 bytes. It is IMPOSSIBLE to store a random integer value in a char variable.

hence, I would prefer you to use the datatype string instead for storing input of multiple datatypes.

Comment: you are assuming C++. Admittedly, it is both confusing and infuriating when people tag their ambiguous questions with both C and C++.

Comment: I kinda already solved this problem by changing the datatype but they said we are supposed to use char. The thing is, char only takes one character. Maybe it's a trick question.

Comment: well, then one alternative way would be you can take user input one character at a time and then print those char values without space which would give us the desired output, only using two char variables instead of one.

Comment: it depends on what kind of problem you are dealing with though